# log-offset in rpart regression tree

Tags: r, regression, cart, poisson-regression, offset

I have understood that one commonly adds log(exposure) as an offset in the formula for GLMs, when dealing with poisson distributed rate data. I am dealing with insurance claim data where I want to predict the frequency i.e. #Claims/Exposure using a regression tree in R. My question is whether it is reasonable to add an log(exposure) offset here aswell? See code below for an example of what I would like to do.

**CODE**

```
tree <- rpart ( claims ~ age + ac + power + gas + brand + area + dens + ct
+ offset ( log ( expo )) ,
data = dat , method =" poisson ", parms = list ( shrink =1) ,
control = rpart . control ( xval =10 , minbucket =10000 , cp =0.001))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [section 8 of the rpart vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf), and they write:

```
The y variable for Poisson partitioning may be a two column
matrix containing the observation time in column 1 and the number of events in column 2
```

So we can try that for an example:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

dat = MASS::Insurance
mdl = rpart(as.matrix(dat[,c("Holders","Claims")]) ~ District + Group + Age,data=dat,method="poisson")
rpart.plot(mdl)
```

[image]

And we can check the fit versus the rate:

```
plot(predict(fit),dat$Claims/dat$Holders)
```

[image]